# Project Euler #53 : What am I doing wrong

Tags: java

So I'm trying to do what I thought would be a simple problem in Java. I don't know if it's because I'm new to Java, or that I'm just making a silly mistake, but I'm getting 3341, which is the wrong answer.

Link to Question: https://projecteuler.net/problem=53

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {

public static BigInteger[] factorial = new BigInteger[101];
static public void main(String[] args)
{
    factorial[0] = BigInteger.ONE;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        factorial[i] = factorial[i-1].multiply( BigInteger.valueOf(i) );

    int count = 0;

    for(int n = 1; n <= 100; n++)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r <= n; r++)
        {
            if( choose(n, r) > 1000000)
            {
                count++;
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println("There are " + count + " values > 1,000,000 ");
}

static public long choose(int n, int r)
{
    return ( factorial[n].divide( ( factorial[r].multiply(factorial[n-r]) ) ) ).longValue();
}
```

}

Comment: I've gotten help here once before on an euler question, not to mention the dozens of other euler questions that have gotten legitimate responses. Im not asking for the correct code, just a hint as to what im doing wrong. I've been looking at this code for a long time and have no idea as to whats wrong with it.

Comment: So in the context of what I mentioned above, can someone explain why my question was down-voted?

Comment: Recommend you add a link to the actual question

Comment: Done. But I would've thought that would be something SO users would fine easy to google.

Answer (score 0):

Some of those numbers are pretty large.  Certainly larger than would fit into a `long` value.

Try doing all the calculations, including the comparisons, as `BigInteger`.

```
public static BigInteger choose(int n, int r)
{
    return factorial[n].divide(factorial[r].multiply(factorial[n - r]));
}
```

And then in the main code, something like:

```
final BigInteger max = BigInteger.valueOf(1000000);

for (int n = 1; n <= 100; n++)
{
    for (int r = 0; r <= n; r++)
    {
        if (choose(n, r).compareTo(max) > 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I assumed the numbers would be small enough to fit in a long.